# Calling function through checkbox in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am needing some help with this, I am not sure if it is at all possible... With my application I have area that has a list of checkboxes. I need each of these checkboxes to call their own function. I have to tried the bind attribute but I have no luck on using that. I am now trying to use the onchange event but cant seem to pass anything through.

```
    <div class="dropdown-custom">
    <input type="checkbox" id="dropdown" style="display: none">
    <label class="dropdown-face" for="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-text">Dropdown</div>
        
    </label>
    <ul class="dropdown-items">
        <input type="checkbox" @onchange="eventArgs => { Zone1Checked(); }" id="zone1" style="visibility: visible">
        <label class="inputi-plain" for="zone1" />
        <div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <InputCheckBox  id="zone2"  style="visibility: visible" />
        <label class="input-plain" for="zone2">
         
        </label>
        <div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="zone3" style="visibility: visible">
        <label class="input-plain" for="zone3">
            Zone 3
        </label>
        <div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="zone4" style="visibility: visible">
        <label class="input-plain" for="zone4">
            Zone 4
        </label>
        <div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="zone5" style="visibility: visible">
        <label class="input-plain" for="zone5">
            Zone 5
        </label>
        <div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="zone6" style="visibility: visible">
        <label class="input-plain" for="zone6">
            Zone 6
        </label>
        <div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="zone7" style="visibility: visible">
        <label class="input-plain" for="zone7">
            Zone 7
        </label>
        <div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="zone9" style="visibility: visible">
        <label class="input-plain" for="zone9">
            Zone 9
        </label>
        <div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="zone10" style="visibility: visible">
        <label class="input-plain" for="zone10">
            Zone 10
        </label>
        <div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="zone2" style="visibility: visible">
        <label class="input-plain" for="zone11">
            Zone 11
        </label>
        <div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="zone12"  style="visibility: visible">
        <label class="input-plain" for="zone12">
            Zone 12
        </label>
    </ul>
</div>
<svg>
    <filter id="goo">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur"/>
        <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18  -7" result="goo"/>
        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo"/>
    </filter>
</svg>

    @code {
    
        public bool ZoneChecked1 { get; set; }
    
        
        public void Zone1Checked()
        {
            
                Console.Write("I got ya working!");
            ZoneChecked1 = true;
    
        }
        
        public void Zone2Checked()
        {
            
        }
        public void Zone3Checked()
        {
            
        }
        public void Zone4Checked()
        {
            
        }
        public void Zone5Checked()
        {
            
        }
        public void Zone6Checked()
        {
            
        }
        public void Zone7Checked()
        {
            
        }
        public void Zone8Checked()
        {
            
        }
        public void Zone9Checked()
        {
            
        }
        public void Zone10Checked()
        {
            
        }
        public void Zone11Checked()
        {
            
        }
        public void Zone12Checked()
        {
            
        }
    
        private void Callback(ChangeEventArgs obj)
        {
            Console.Write("I got ya working!");
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Dictionary based demo of checkbox state being tracked.

```
@page "/Checkbox"
<h3>Checkbox</h3>

@foreach (var cb in Checkboxes)
{
    <div class="m-2 p-2">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="@cb.Value" @onchange="(e) => Checked(e, cb.Key)" />Input Check 1 - @cb.Value
   </div>
    @if (cb.Value)
    {
    <div class="m-4 p-2 bg-secondary">
        It is a good platform to learn programming.
        It is an educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment drive
        of product based companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc with
        a free online placement preparation course. The course focuses
        on various MCQ's & Coding question likely to be asked in the
        interviews & make your upcoming placement season efficient and
        successful.
    </div>
        }
    }

@code {

    protected void Checked(ChangeEventArgs e, int no)
    {
        var x = e.Value;
        Checkboxes[no] = (bool)e.Value;
    }

    protected Dictionary<int, bool> Checkboxes = new Dictionary<int, bool>
{
        { 1, false },
        { 2, false },
        { 3, true },
    };
}
```

You can only use `InputCheckbox` inside a form control in Blazor.

Comment: So with the using the InputCheckbox will that require me to use the Editform? As, well I should then be able to just use the @bind-Value correct?

Comment: Yes, but you then can't use `onchange` to detect a change in the value and if you want to react to a change event you'll need a different mechanism - usually a trigger/event on the setter for the value.

Comment: Awesome I took what you said and applied it, I was able to get it work thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changed how I was using my onclick, I was anble to get the output to the console... I also didn't realize that I wasn't doing a WriteLine for my console command.

```
    <input type="checkbox" @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs e) =>Zone1Checked(e))" value="@ZoneChecked1" id="zone1" style="visibility: visible">
        <label id="zone1" for="zone1">
            Zone 1
        </label>
private void Zone1Checked(ChangeEventArgs checkedValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(checkedValue);
        ZoneChecked1 = bool.Parse(checkedValue.Value.ToString());
        if (ZoneChecked1)
        {
            string s = "Blah";
            Console.WriteLine("work please");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("function is being called!");
        }

    }
```